# Incompatible libgmp.a error when building Pycrypto 2.6

Tags: python, gmp, pycrypto

I have build the gmp 5.1.1 library using gcc 4.7.2 all in the Windows-7 environment.
I configured the build with ./configure and commanded the make and after finished the
make check without any errors.
However, when I put the resulting libgmp.a into the Python33/libs and lunch the

```
c:\Users\egargio\Downloads\pycrypto-2.6\pycrypto-2.6>c:\Python33\python setup.py
 build_ext --compiler=mingw32
```

the following errors reporting incompatibility for libgmp.a occur:

```
c:\Users\egargio\Downloads\pycrypto-2.6\pycrypto-2.6>c:\Python33\python setup.py
 build_ext --compiler=mingw32
running build_ext
running build_configure
building 'Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath' extension
C:\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/
-Ic:\Python33\include -Ic:\Python33\include -c src/_fastmath.c -o build\temp.win
-amd64-3.3\Release\src\_fastmath.o
writing build\temp.win-amd64-3.3\Release\src\_fastmath.def
C:\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe -shared -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -s build\temp.win-am
d64-3.3\Release\src\_fastmath.o build\temp.win-amd64-3.3\Release\src\_fastmath.d
ef -Lc:\Python33\libs -Lc:\Python33\PCbuild\amd64 -lgmp -lpython33 -lmsvcr100 -o
 build\lib.win-amd64-3.3\Crypto\PublicKey\_fastmath.pyd
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw3
2/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:\Python33\libs/libgmp.a when searching for
 -lgmp
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw3
2/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:\Python33\libs\libgmp.a when searching for
 -lgmp
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw3
2/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:\Python33\libs/libgmp.a when searching for
 -lgmp
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw3
2/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgmp
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Please any suggestions ? Thanks.

-- Giorgio

Comment: Try specifying `ABI=32` or `ABI=64` when configuring GMP? (see the doc for valid options)

Comment: With ./configure ABI=32 for both libgmp and pycrypto, I have got that error. I cannot compile with ABI=64 as mingw64 reports the error:                                                
c:\Python33\python setup.py
 build_ext --compiler=mingw64
running build_ext
error: don't know how to compile C/C++ code on platform 'nt' with 'mingw64' compiler

Comment: `file ..../_fastmath.o` and `file c:\Python33\libs/libgmp.a` (assuming you have something like the `file` command, otherwise a right click in the explorer might help). The most likely issue is still that one is 32 bits and the other 64 bits, so whatever way you have to check that...